# noobie array question

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic

i have a 2 data classes

first:

```
public class Question {

    public CharSequence question;
    public Answer answers[];

}
```

second:

```
public class Answer {

    public CharSequence text;
    public int number;
}
```

now i want to save an Answer to Question:

```
Question qstn.answers = new Answer[2];

[...]
```

But i got an NullPointerException. Whats wrong? Can't I change the length of an Array in an other class?

Comment: I just have to say that this is a good place to use a List or Set instead of an array. A List or Set can grow without having a preset size.

Comment: now i use "public ArrayList<Data> answer;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you created a new instance of Question first e.g.

```
Question qstn = new Question();
qstn.answers = new Answer[2];
```

Also unless you're optimising judiciously, then you'd probably want to give encapsulation a go and make the instance variables private.  Access through a public API e.g. getters or/and setters.

Also you may want to instantiate answers when the Object is created e.g.

```
public class Question {

    public CharSequence question;
    public Answer answers[] = new Answer[2];

}
```

Or you could do this in the constructor of Question (you'd need to add a Constructor, as the compiler will be generating you a non-arg Constructor by default with the way things stand).

Answer (score 4):

> Can't I change the length of an Array
>   in an other class?

That is not the problem.

The problem is that you haven't initialized `qstn` yet.

What you should be doing is:

```
Question qstn = new Question();
qstn.answers = new Answer[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to instantiate your Question class, first:

```
Question qstn = new Question();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Question qstn = new Question();

qstn.answers = new Answer[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trying to access the array incorrectly.

```
 Question qstn = new Question();
 qstn.answers = new Answer[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can change the length of arrays in another class.

Please check whether you have initialized the variable `qstn`.

```
Question qstn = new Question();
```